# Keyboard comes with tabbar.. how to get only keyboard

Tags: android

I have one problem in the Tabbar with text box, when i click on text box keyboard comes but the tabbar comes over the keyboard, and i want to get the keyboard only tabbar should not be comes over the keyboard.

Screen scroll automatically when keyboard comes.

Comment: Can you define more clearly what tabbar is? Perhaps a screenshot of your app?

Comment: you can see the screen shot from the following location http://picasaweb.google.com/k.amit.gupta/Test#5558745745727665874

Comment: Ugly fix. Loose the scrollview or make it non scrollable. (SRY but there doesn't seem to be another way)

Answer (score 5):

Add this property in your Tab activity tag in `AndroidMainfestfile`,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```